# Errores con la división de números primos guardados en un array. C++

Tags: c++, array, matemáticas, números-primos

He estado intentando crear un programa para descomponer canónicamente un número entero "N", pero antes de ello tenía que calcular todos los números primos menores que este, para así luego comprobar el total de potencias de cada primo de "N", pero esto se ha vuelto un gran dolor de cabeza, ya que en he modificado dos veces el código: en la primera ocasión el limite hasta donde funcionaba el número "N" era de 8 y en la segunda ocasión (que es esta) el limite ha sido el "13", en dónde el vector dónde guardaba los números primos empieza a soltar más datos de los que debería botar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int numero, primos=1, divisores=0;
    int totalDeNumerosPrimos=0, *p=&totalDeNumerosPrimos;
    int conjuntoDePrimos[*p];
    std::cout<<"Ingresar el numero: "; std::cin>>numero; 
    while (primos<=numero)
    {
        for (int divisor=1; divisor <= primos; divisor++)
        {
            if(primos%divisor==0)
            {
                divisores++;
                if(divisores>2)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(divisores==2)
        {
            conjuntoDePrimos[totalDeNumerosPrimos]=primos;
            if(primos!=numero)
            {
                totalDeNumerosPrimos++;
            }
        }
        divisores=0;
        if(primos<=numero)
        {
            primos++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < totalDeNumerosPrimos; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<conjuntoDePrimos[i]<<" "; 
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Tienen alguna solución o soy yo el que ha errado en alguna parte¿?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y poner un ejemplo de entrada y salida de tu programa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás asumiendo que el ordenador hace magia negra y es capaz de adaptar el tamaño de los objetos por iniciativa propia:

```
int totalDeNumerosPrimos=0, *p=&totalDeNumerosPrimos;
int conjuntoDePrimos[*p];
```

Lo primero que llama poderosamente la atención en estas líneas es la última:

```
int conjuntoDePrimos[*p];
```

Los arrays como este se declaran en la pila del programa, es decir, acabarán teniendo variables por debajo y por encima en memoria, es decir, tienen un hueco de **tamaño fijo**.

Esto implica también, que el tamaño debe ser conocido en **tiempo de compilación**, básicamente esto quiere decir que `*p` debería ser un literal. Como no es un literal, entonces estás intentando crear un VLA (*Variable Length Array*), característica **no soportada por el estándar**, luego no se debería usar. No me voy a explayar en qué es un VLA, este tema se ha tratado innumerables veces en StackOverflow, así que si buscas un poco lo encontrarás.

En resumen, tu pretendes que el array `conjuntoDePrimos` se redimensione de forma mágica según vayas modificando la variable `totalDeNumerosPrimos`, pero eso no va a pasar. Si quieres ese comportamiento se lo tienes que dar tu. Esto es justamente lo que hacen los contenedores de la STL, como `std::vector`.

Básicamente, si quieres un array cuyo tamaño sea variable, debes usar memoria dinámica y jugar con punteros a la hora de redimensionar el array:

```
int * conjuntoDePrimos = nullptr;
// ...

// Redimensionamos a un array de un elemento
int* ptr = static_cast<int*>(realloc(conjuntoDePrimos, 1 * sizeof(int)));
if (ptr == nullptr )
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Sin memoria";
    exit(1);
}
conjuntoDePrimos = ptr;
// ...

// Redimensionamos a un array de dos elemento
ptr = static_cast<int*>(realloc(conjuntoDePrimos, 2 * sizeof(int)));
if (ptr == nullptr )
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Sin memoria";
    exit(1);
}
conjuntoDePrimos = ptr;
```

Esto es bastante engorroso, por eso en C++ tenemos los contenedores de la STL. Con ellos no tienes que preocuparte de gestionar el tamaño de la colección, de eso ya se encarga el propio contenedor:

```
std::vector<int> conjuntoDePrimos;
conjuntoDePrimos.push_back(2);
conjuntoDePrimos.push_back(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

si la solucion es

```
nt * conjuntoDePrimos = nullptr;
// ...

// Redimensionamos a un array de un elemento
int* ptr = static_cast<int*>(realloc(conjuntoDePrimos, 1 * sizeof(int)));
if (ptr == nullptr )
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Sin memoria";
    exit(1);
}
conjuntoDePrimos = ptr;
// ...

// Redimensionamos a un array de dos elemento
ptr = static_cast<int*>(realloc(conjuntoDePrimos, 2 * sizeof(int)));
if (ptr == nullptr )
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Sin memoria";
    exit(1);
}
conjuntoDePrimos = ptr;
```